# Generalisation using dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want to improve and shorten the following function using a dictionary:

```
def loop_solution(filename1=None,filename2=None,filename3=None,filename4=None):
    if (filename1!=None): im1=import_file_astro(filename1)
    if (filename2!=None): im2=import_file_astro(filename2)
    if (filename3!=None): im3=import_file_astro(filename3)
    if (filename4!=None): im4=import_file_astro(filename4)
```

I thought of using the following snipet:

```
mydic={'im'+str(i):import_file_astro(filename1) for i in range(1,5) if filename1!=None}
```

but of course I need a way to loop through the `filename`s. I've thought of using `exec` but I've read that it should be avoided.
Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `def loop_solution(*filenames):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def loop_solution(filenames):
    files = {}
    for index, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1):
        if filename is not None:
            files['im' + str(index)] = import_file_astro(filename)
```

or, if you want it as a dict comprehension

```
def loop_solution(filenames):
    return {'im'+str(index): import_file_astro(filename) for index, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1) if filename is not None}
```

Comment: How could `filename` ever be `None` in this context actually ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: if the `filenames` list is created from another function, which might return None is some cases.

Comment: I'd personnaly wouldn't be that defensive - the function expects a list of filenames, if the list contains anything else than valid filenames then it's the caller's fault, period. Else you should also test against any other possible type other than a string, and even then those might still not be valid filenames...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: me neither, but it's not my question, so I'm keeping the answer as close as possible to the original version